# Android Room can not process my classes because it can not resolve all their dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to integrate Room in my kotlin project which also uses databinding.I have implemented all the required classes (I think so!) but when I try to build the project I get the below error message and can not find out what is causing this error or what am I missing

Here is the build log

```
e: [PATH_TO_PROJECT]\dataaccess\local\AppDatabase.java:7: error: android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract class AppDatabase extends android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^
e: [PATH_TO_PROJECT]\dataaccess\local\BusinessLocalDataSource.java:7: error: android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract class BusinessLocalDataSource implements [PACKAGE].dataaccess.local.BaseDao<[PACKAGE].dataaccess.local.model.Business>, [PACKAGE].dataaccess.BusinessDataSource {
                ^
e: [PATH_TO_PROJECT]\dataaccess\local\model\Business.java:7: error: android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class Business {
             ^
:app:kaptAppDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptAppDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptAppDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:16)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithKotlincTask.compile(KaptWithKotlincTask.kt:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 31 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

This is my AppDatabase class

```
@Database(version = 1, entities = [(Business::class)])
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun businessDao(): BusinessLocalDataSource

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                            AppDatabase::class.java,
                            "app.db")
                            .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```

My business entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "business")
data class Business(

        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = "uuid")
        var uuid: String = "",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
        var title: String = "",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "address")
        var address: String = "",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "votesCount")
        var votesCount: Int = 0,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "isSpecial")
        var isSpecial: Boolean = false,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "lat")
        var lat: Double? = 0.0,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "lon")
        var lon: Double? = null,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "imageUrl")
        var imageUrl: String = "",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "dateSeen")
        var dateSeen: Long = 0
)
```

My BaseDao interface

```
interface BaseDao<T> {

    @Delete
    fun delete(t: List<T>): Int

    @Delete
    fun delete(t: T): Int

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(t: List<T>): List<Long>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(t: T): Long

    @Update
    fun update(t: List<T>): Int

    @Update
    fun update(t: T): Int
}
```

And here is the BusinessLocalDataSource which implements BaseDao

```
@Dao
abstract class BusinessLocalDataSource : BaseDao<Business>, BusinessDataSource {

    override fun getTitleSuggestions(request: TitleSuggesterRequest): Maybe<TitleSuggesterResponse> {
        TODO("Currently local data source does not support getting title suggestions")
    }

    override fun getPreSearch(): Maybe<PreSearchResponse> {
        TODO("Currently local data source does not support getting pre-search data")
    }

    @Query("SELECT * from business")
    abstract override fun getLastSeen(): Flowable<List<Business>>

    override fun saveLastSeen(business: Business) {
        insert(business)
    }
}
```

And here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    // ...

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
            force 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
            force 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
            force 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId '[PACKAGE]'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"
        }

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix '.DEBUG'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxkotlin.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/app_debug.kotlin_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    // ...
}

configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jre7'
}

dependencies {

    // ...

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1"
}
```

I really do not know what to check anymore. It would be great if someone help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your gradle version? 
Sometimes it happen with some update versions like 5.1.1.

Comment: I ended up using another library at that time since I couldn't find that what was causing this error. But after upgrading project to `AndroidX` and used latest version of `Room`, it worked correctly without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forget to add **apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"** in build.gradle[app].

Answer (score 0):

Please run the failed script separately to get more details:

```
./gradlew kaptAppDebugKotlin
```

PS. This not solves you issue, but you can simplify your `getInstance()` function this way:

```
fun getInstance(context: Context) = INSTANCE
                ?: Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "app.db")
                        .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error occur to me i chnaged the sequence in build file, my sequence is:

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Answer (score 0):

Room generated classes requires the jetbrains annotations classes to work properly. As you're excluding the annotations module, you're getting the error. Remove the following code to fix it.

```
configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jre7'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763363/when-building-android-project-with-android-gradle-plugin-v-3-5-2-my-builds-fail) issue, check it, hope you can use solutions there for fixing your problem.